# "generations now past" - is "now" appropriate here?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> > ...structure will stand for generations to come, just as it did for generations now past...

Is the word **now** grammatically correct in this usage or even necessary?

Comment: It is correct. You may keep past before generations, but the presented version is better.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct, and metrically preferable.  Say the line with the "now" and without while beating out the rhythm with your hand.  Without the "now", you get an extra measure/foot, and you can't match up the rhythms of the two instances of "generations".

> |structure will|stand for gener|ations to|come,|just as it |did for gener|ations now|past|
>
> |structure will|stand for gener|ations to|come,|just as it |did for|gener|ations|past|